# Cannot convert objects to pointers C++

Tags: pointers, c++11

I've stayed up all night trying to figure this out (it's now 7am where I'm at...).

I'm having trouble setting the address of an instantiated object to a pointer. Here's the main function:

```
#include "position_vector.h"
int main(){
    PositionVector res = PositionVector(10);
    PositionVector * ptr;
    ptr = &res;                   // <--- WHERE IT BREAKS
}
```

A stripped down version of the h file "position_vector.h":

```
#include<iostream>

typedef uint32_t word_t;
class PositionVector {
    public:
        word_t * vec;
/*some other member variables */
        PositionVector();
        PositionVector(size_t len);
        PositionVector & operator & ();
        PositionVector & operator !();
        ~PositionVector();

/*some other member functions*/
        void resize(size_t len);
};
```

I have another cpp file that defines all the methods in the class.

This is part of some larger set of code but here's the compile that fails:

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -g -Isrc -ggdb  -c -o bin/main.o src/main.cpp
```

It fails with the error:

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -g -Isrc -ggdb  -c -o bin/main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/main.cpp:27:9: error: cannot convert ‘PositionVector’ to ‘PositionVector*’ in assignment
     ptr = &res;
         ^
```

I must be missing something super basic but I've just pulled an all nighter and I have to run to work... so I cant really think full well any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've overloaded `operator&` in your class:

```
class PositionVector {
        // ...
        PositionVector & operator & ();
};
```

When you than try to take the address, the compiler calls your overloaded member function which returns a `PositionVector&`. This cannot be assigned to a `PositionVector*` and thus you get the error.

Comment: Also, if you really want to keep this as the operator return type, you can use `std::addressof` to get a pointer.

Comment: Thanks! You are a life saver... @vu1p3n0x - duly noted. I'm still confused on how to handle heap allocated class members in a stack allocated class but that's for another time...

Comment: @FrancoSolleza The best way is to not handle heap-allocated stack manually at all. Wrap the things in `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for normal objects, and use `std::vector` etc. for arrays. Then you don't have to worry about lifetimes or exception-safety.

Comment: @Jens ***or*** abstract away free-store-allocated memory by putting it in the class and ensuring proper deallocation in the destructor. Don't take my word for it; just read the first 100 pages of Stroustrup's _The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition_.

Comment: @c650 `std::unique_ptr` etc are the abstractions you mentioned. I am a huge fan of the rule of zero (as opposed to the rule of three/five). Basically, only resource-managing classes should have a custom destructor etc. For memory allocations, this has already been done in the standard library. No need for doing it on your own. For other resources, I would use something like the proposed `std::unique_resource` and do it once.